# Trouble with a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a bit of a complicated rewrite scenario that I could use some expert advice on. I have a directory, "/directory" that contains some files. I would like to rewrite requests for files that don't exist in that directory to another directory which also exists, keeping the original directory in the URL and returning 404 for invalid paths. example

This exists:

```
/directory/file.php
```

This does not exist:

```
/directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php
```

...but it does exist here:

```
/another_directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php
```

So I would like

```
/directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php to refer to /another_directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php
```

... but if the folder/file doesn't exist in /another_directory/ the rule should return a 404.

I've tried various combinations but they all either don't return a 404 or they redirect. This is my latest attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/another_directory/$1 f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/another_directory/$1 d 
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ /another_directory/$1 [L, QSA]
```

If it helps to explain why I have this scenario, /another_directory/ is full of periodically regenerated static files that appear to be in the same directory as the existing files in /directory/ I am moving away from dynamic pages to generated static ones and don't want to mess with my serps and want to keep this large number of generated files isolated from the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I understood from your explanation:

```
/directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php
```

This should be rewritten to

```
/another_directory/subdirectory/anotherfile.php
```

whether it exists or not. If I'm right, here's your answer, otherwise tell me more!

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/another_directory/$1 -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/another_directory/$1 -d 
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*) another_directory/$1 [L,S=1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)  - [L]
RewriteRule (.*)   404.php?uri=/$1&id=1 [L]
```